# Ad Hoc iOS App Causing UI Bugs

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, scroll, adhoc

I've been running my app through XCode and all the rows in the UITableView are the correct height (they vary in length through overriding tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)

But when I archive the same app to an Ad Hoc version and run it on the same device, the rows on the UITableView have seemingly random height.  At one point in development, it was just rubber banding (contentSize == frame, even though it is clearly bigger).

I checked settings and for the most part, they are nearly identical.  I know there's not a tonne of information to go by here but if anyone has any clues as to why it's messing up my UI, please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Its very unlikely this is the cause but the only time I've seen differences between dev and prod builds it was beacuse code optimization was 0 for dev and full for prod. Maybe check that ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the bug.  Turns out a float var in a method that determined row height was static in ad-hoc build, which is why the rows were increasing in height (not random).